# How set my main menu (custom link and category) in my shop with two language version?

Tags: magento2, menu

How to set my main menu (custom link and category) in my shop with two language version?

On second language version my menu will be translated.

> About us(custom link)  (en)  ->  About us(custom link) (different
>   language)
>
> Category 1 (en)  ->  Category 1 (different language)
>
> Category 2 (en)  ->  Category 2 (different language)

Answer (score 0):

I know how set multilanguage for category. 
Catalog > Categories > Store view > [change Language]

In categtory:
check enable/disable Category and Include in menu